# Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework - ORA-01918: user 'dbo' does not exist

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-migrations, odp.net

I am trying to implemente code First Migrations with Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 6.121.1.0 provider, but with no success at all.

As I am receiving a ORA-code, I am assuming that the connection are been opened successfully. But the Migrations are failing because, maybe, the provider are behaving as a SQL Server, instead of Oracle. I think that beacause it is traying to use 'dbo' as default schema.

Here is my web.config settings:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
   <section name="entityFramework"
             type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
             requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
             type="OracleInternal.Common.ODPMSectionHandler, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
      <context type="MyProject.Context.MainContext, MyProject.Context">
        <databaseInitializer type="MyProject.Context.Config.ContextInitializer, MyProject.Context" />
      </context>
    </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" />    
    <providers>    
      <provider invariantName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" 
                type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework.EFOracleProviderServices, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework, Version=6.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver"
           invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
           description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver"
           type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MainContext"
         providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"
         connectionString="Data Source=OracleServer:1521/BRSYSDS;User ID=USER;Password=PASSWORD;" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- other settings -->
</configuration>
```

Here the Stacktrace:

> [OracleException (0x77e): ORA-01918: user 'dbo' does not exist]
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone) +652
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean bFirstIterationDone) +39
>   OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isFromEF) +7480
>   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +678
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c) +10
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch(TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed) +72
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +357
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() +104
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(DbTransaction transaction, MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +152
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext) +82
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection) +626
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e() +19
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation) +9
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction) +194
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements) +7
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, XDocument targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto) +825
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading) +564
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId) +404
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +447
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b() +13
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +422
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration) +78
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.DatabaseCreator.CreateDatabase(InternalContext internalContext, Func`3 createMigrator, ObjectContext objectContext) +89
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.CreateDatabase(ObjectContext objectContext, DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +116
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Database.Create(DatabaseExistenceState existenceState) +218
>
>   System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseAlways`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext context) +137

Comment: Please, correct this mistake - **<defaultConnectionFactory type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess" />**

Comment: Tks @lewis, that is really a mistake. I already update for us.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was resolved by Thiago Lunardi's response. Thank you. I didn't have enough reputation to vote up your response. To mention here, I succeeded after setting my schema name in UPPERCASE.

Put this in your Context file under your new dbContext class, like this:

```
public partial class MyAppContext : DbContext
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("UPPERCASE_SCHEMA_NAME");
...
```

Comment: Voted as the answer to avoid vote my own. :) tks Отгонтөгс Миймаа

Comment: Uppercase is the key. I had the same problem.

Comment: where do I insert this?

Comment: @RageCompex at you DbContext definition.
`public class MainContext : DbContext, IDbContext
    {
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("VSN");
//...
}
}`

Comment: UPPER CASE it is! I am trying new project to use Entity Framework (EF) Code First with Oracle Data Provider for .NET (ODP.NET). I have following code in .Net. User "SA" needs to be uppercase.      
        {
            modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("SA");
        }

Answer (score 18):

I solve this just setting the default schema at modelBuilder

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MyOracleSchema");

    // ...
}
```

Comment: and try to uppercase the schema (it's your username) ;)

Answer (score 2):

Setting default schema didn't work for me.
I found the solution by customizing migrations history table to set a different schema.

You can find a solution here: [LINK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456841).

Answer (score 2):

User Dbo also comes in case of missing fully qualified name of the Table. Which may not map to the right Table in the database.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use Automatic Migrations (as I was), then note: `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema` whouldn't help until you switch to explicit migrations.

From [Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E56485_01/win.121/e55744/entityCodeFirst.htm#ODPNT8312):

> Code First Automatic Migrations is limited to working with the **dbo** schema only. Due to this limitation it is recommended to use code-based migrations, that is, add explicit migrations through the Add-Migration command

Comment: How do I switch to explicit migrations?!

Comment: @ascriven that is, add explicit migrations through the Add-Migration command.

Answer (score 1):

in Code First you can use the DataAnnotations for Table .

**[Table("Emplpoyee",Schema="YOUR SCHEMA NAME"]**

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I placed my schema name in OnModelCreating() method.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MyOracleSchema");

    // ...
}
```

But, setting schema name in UPPERCASE didn't work for me. I added below mentioned code in Confifuration.cs and it worked !!

Go to Migrations -> Configuration.cs

```
 class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<CodeFirstOracleProject.Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        var historyContextFactory = GetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
        SetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
                                 (dbc, schema) => historyContextFactory.Invoke(dbc, "YourSchemaName"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case writing schema name in Uppercase wasn't sufficient I had to use `toUpper()` function as such :

```
 modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("YOURSCHEMA".ToUpper())
```

alongside adding

```
   public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        var historyContextFactory = GetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
        SetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
                                 (dbc, schema) => historyContextFactory.Invoke(dbc, "YOURSCHEMA".ToUpper()));
    }
```

removed the migrations and regenerating them fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a beginner, the major issue I had with the answers here was, what does user 'dbo' has to do with schema name.

After researching, here is what I found.

**In oracle, A Schema is a collection of database objects. A schema is owned by a database user and has the same name as the user.**

**The default schema for entity framework is however dbo, and you can override this as in the code listing below:**

```
  modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("YOURSCHEMA".ToUpper())
```

For oracle, **"YOURSCHEMA"** has to be the *user_id* for the database you are connected to.

Then you need to add the below to your configuration file

```
public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        var historyContextFactory = GetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client");
        SetHistoryContextFactory("Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client",
                                 (dbc, schema) => historyContextFactory.Invoke(dbc, "YOURSCHEMA".ToUpper()));
    }
```

Finally, delete the migration files generated and rerun **Add-Migration** again.

I hope this will help somebody.