# ORA-01918 error when working with Identity Membership and MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle11g, odp.net, membership-provider

I am trying to use the MVC (version 5) identity membership provider with an Oracle database (11 g).  I have already created a database and installed all the necessary tables (*ORA_ASPNET_APPLICATIONS, ORA_ASPNET_USERS, etc*).  I have also downloaded *Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio*, and have installed and referenced the *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess* and *Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework* assemblies.  When I try to add a new user, the application breaks at this line:

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

And I get the following error:

> ORA-01918: user 'dbo' does not exist

I looked at the stack track and -- based on the contents -- it looks like the application is trying to create a new database (see below):

> System.Data.Entity.CreateDatabaseIfNotExists`1.InitializeDatabase(TContext
>   context)

I'm not sure why, though, since the database already exists.  I have only one connection string in my web.config, and it points to the Oracle database I created.

Has anyone been able to get the MVC membership provider to work with Oracle?  If so, can anyone provide me with any assistance?  I already looked at this link -- [Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework - ORA-01918: user 'dbo' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250555/oracle-manageddataaccess-entityframework-ora-01918-user-dbo-does-not-exist) -- but I'm not using code-first, so I don't think any of the suggestions apply in my situation.

My connection string is below:

```
 <add name="OracleDbContext" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" connectionString="User Id=MyOracleAccountUserName;Password=MyOracleAccountPassword;Data Source=MyOracleDataSource" />
```

I don't think it's the connection string, though.  I also tried overriding the OnModelCreating method as follows:

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MySchemaName");


        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("ORA_ASPNET_USERS");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("ORA_ASPNET_ROLES");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("ORA_ASPNET_USERSINROLES");


    }
```

But, when I do that, I get a different error: ORA-00904: "Extent1"."UserName": invalid identifier.

Comment: Your connection string is wrong? Show us your connection string in web.config

Comment: I added the connection string

Comment: I figured it out.  The tables in my database were based on the ASP.Net Membership model, not on the Identity model.  I had used the database table scripts as provided by Oracle.  So, I had to scrap those and create new ones using migrations.  Once I did that, I was able to create new users.

Comment: You should post your answer... somebody else might find it beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("MSN");

your schema name should be UPPERCASE