# OracleException: ORA-01918: user 'dbo' does not exist

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have this error trying to connect to remote oracle db with EntityFramework 6. I've seen similar question
[Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework - ORA-01918: user 'dbo' does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27250555/oracle-manageddataaccess-entityframework-ora-01918-user-dbo-does-not-exist?noredirect=1&lq=1)
but it that my schema name is really lowercase (connection == schema, right?) - I checked it with Oracle SQL developer. My connection string

> DATA SOURCE =
>     (DESCRIPTION =
>       (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = srvhost)(PORT = 1521))
>       (CONNECT_DATA =
>         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
>         (SERVICE_NAME = cmmd)
>       )
>     );PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=usr;PASSWORD=pwd;Max Pool Size=40;Incr Pool Size=1;Decr Pool Size=1;

so this code does not help

```
builder.HasDefaultSchema("ORACLE"); // error ORA-01918: user 'ORACLE' does not exist

builder.HasDefaultSchema("oracle"); // error ORA-01918: user 'oracle' does not exist
```

[image: Oracle SQL developer]
Edit 1:

```
public class OracleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public OracleDbContext() : base(new OracleConnection(Tools.GetConnectionString()), true)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        MapMonitoringObject(modelBuilder);
    }

    public DbSet<MonitoringObject> MonitoringObjects { get; set; }

    private void MapMonitoringObject (DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        //builder.HasDefaultSchema("");
    }

}
```

Comment: In Oracle schema = user. Try `builder.HasDefaultSchema("");`

Comment: @IvanStoev, now I get an error "value cannot be null. parameter name seq owner". Not sure if it's better or not..

Comment: @IvanStoev if it's important, I am trying to read a single value from db

Comment: OracleDbContext context = new OracleDbContext();
     var query = context.MonitoringObjects.FirstOrDefault();

Comment: Just to be sure: there's no Sql Server provider name lurking in your config somewhere?

Comment: @GertArnold don't think so. My only configuration comes from OracleDbContext constructor with calling base(new OracleConnection(Tools.GetConnectionString()), true)

Comment: @GertArnold  do you know how can I check Schema name for sure? The only info I've found about Oracle "connections"

Comment: @GertArnold well, I can't even connect to db, it's devastating sort of experience.

Comment: your entity framework thinks you're connecting to a SQL Server, hence the 'dbo' reference.

Comment: also, user names/schemas in oracle aren't case sensitive unless you quote them - and as a best practice, you should never have quoted schemeas/users, precisely to avoid the issue you're worried about now

Comment: @thatjeffsmith please have a look, added source code to the question

Comment: @thatjeffsmith haven't seen any quotes. is connection the same thing as schema in oracle sql developer? I couldn't find a clear answer to this.

Comment: @GrumpyAndroid user/schema are synonymous in Oracle. User is the account you logon as, schema is the collection of objects owned by that user - basically

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, "schema" means user, because stored in dba_users. So I queried it, picked the one, added in HasDefaultSchema and error is gone (but returned null for now). I really tried to find what means "schema" in Oracle terms, but it's so easily confused with "database" concept.